# Redmine plugin Javascript Asset do not reload in Development mode

Tags: reload, redmine-plugins

I am working with the following versions of Redmine and Ruby:

```
Environment:
  Redmine version                          2.0.1.devel
  Ruby version                             1.9.3 (x86_64-darwin11.2.0)
  Rails version                            3.2.3
  Environment                              development
  Database adapter                         Mysql2
```

However when working on plugin development in dev mode itself, the javascript files do not reload on each request.

What is the work around for this?

Answer (score 3):

If you include your javascript like folowing:
`<%= javascript_include_tag 'plugin', :plugin => 'redmine_plugin' %>`,
you have to restart your rails server each time, when do some changes in javascript or css file.

You have to do it, because javascript files from your plugins directory `plugin/assets/javascript` is copied to application public directory `plugin_assets/redmine_plugin/javascripts/` during restart of server.